# how to get current session in onRouteRequest

Tags: session, playframework, global

Hi i am using play framework 2.3(java)
I would like to handle session in onRouteRequest

```
public play.api.mvc.Handler onRouteRequest(RequestHeader request) {
 /*
 for eaxmple. I want to like this.
 Is possilbe?
 if (!session.get("userId")) {
    redirect("loginPage.html");
 }
 */
}
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do

```
if(session("userId")==null){
     redirect("page url to redirect");
}
```